# Method references in Java

Tags: java

Sorry this is a training question.

The topic is like this:

```
It is always nice to have one function that can sort array both ascending and descending. 
This function is implemented below and based on bubble sorting algorithm. 
The function takes 2 parameters: array and comparison function.

The comparison function should take 2 parameters and return the minimum of the two if the array should be sorted in the ascending order, 
and the maximum of the two if the array should be sorted in the descending order.

Use isAscending variable to determine if array should be sorted in ascending or descending order. 
If the variable is true, then you need to sort the array in the ascending order, otherwise, in the descending order.
```

Can anyone tell me how to write the BiFunction with the Method references format to make this work?
I did this and it said the compilation error...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isAscending = scanner.nextLine().equals("ascending");
        int[] array = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();

        // write your code here
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> comparator = (x,y) -> {
            if (isAscending) { return Math.min(x, y); }
            return Math.max(x, y);
        };        

        sort(array, comparator);
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> comparator) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (comparator.apply(array[j], array[j + 1]) == array[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is supposed to react like this

Sample Input 1:
ascending
3 5 2 1 4
Sample Output 1:
1 2 3 4 5

Sample Input 2:
descending
3 5 2 1 4
Sample Output 2:
5 4 3 2 1

Error is

```
Compilation error
Main.java:12: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> comparator = (x,y) -> {
                                                           ^
    missing return value
1 error
```

Comment: What exactly is Bifunction with method references?

Comment: Why are you writing your comparator like that rather than using an actual `Comparator`?

Comment: At what part you are getting compilation error??

Comment: And what compilation error are you getting? Your question is radically incomplete without all this information. NB It's not correct to compare the result of a `Comparator` to an array element. They aren't the same kind of data.

Comment: Works for me, what's your error?

Comment: Compilation error
Main.java:12: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> comparator = (x,y) -> {
                                                           ^
    missing return value
1 error

Comment: Please look up the correct return values for `Comparator`. They don't have anything to do with `max()` or `min()`.

Answer (score -1):

OK I found a solution...
But, are there any better way to write this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isAscending = scanner.nextLine().equals("ascending");
        int[] array = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> comparator = (x,y) -> {
            if (isAscending) {
                if (x.compareTo(y) > 0) {
                    return y;
                } else {
                    return x;
                }
            }
            if (x.compareTo(y) > 0) {
                return x;
            } else {
                return y;
            }
        };

        // write your code here

        sort(array, comparator);
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> comparator) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (comparator.apply(array[j], array[j + 1]) == array[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. This is not correct. Look it up, as I advised a month ago.

Comment: I am going to add to that, which was deleted for some reason the first time I posted it. If telling people their solution is wrong, and that they need to consult the documentation, and that they have already been told so is now deemed unacceptable at Stack Overfow there seems little point in the site at all.